# jquery simpledialog2 button event

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, simpledialog

I am using simpledialog2 to show the dialog in mobile.

```
defaultDialogConfig: {
    mode: 'blank',
    dialogForce: false,
    showModal: true,
    headerText: '',
    headerClose: true,
    animate: false,
    zindex: 9999,
    blankContent: '',
    themeDialog: 'b',
    themeInput: 'e',
    themeButtonDefault: false,
    themeHeader: 'a',
    callbackOpen: lockScreen,
    callbackClose: unlockScreen
},
```

calling this simpledialog2

```
var config = defaultDialogConfig;
                $.extend(config, {blankContent: response.address});
                var dialog = $(document.createElement('div'));
                dialog.simpledialog2(config);
```

in my repsone we have a button and I want to add a event to the button.How Can I add an event?

Comment: Follow this : http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/button.html

Comment: I seen this.It is for static buttons where as my button will come in response.

Comment: have you tried event delegation? like using jquery on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve by `live`.

```
$('#button').live("click",function () {
    alert("hi");
})
```

I placed this piece of code below the dialog show.